# Antd table says rowKey should be unique when they already seem to be

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Currently having an issue with some react code.

I have a list of products, each one have 7 items array that have 40 datas under this format that is used as the datasource for a table.

`{label : someStringLabel, key: someUniqueKey, attribute1: someInt,..., attributeN: someInt}`

All tables in the product list are generated using a loop in my render method.

`

```
{productForecast.map((productLocation, index) => {
  let productDescription =
      productLocation.product_description
          .charAt(0)
          .toUpperCase() +
      productLocation.product_description.slice(1) +
      ' - ' +
      productLocation.location_description
          .charAt(0)
          .toUpperCase() +
      productLocation.location_description.slice(1);
  return (
    <>
      <Collapse accordion>
        <Panel header={productDescription} key='1'>
          <Table
            scroll={{ x: true }}
            pagination={false}
            components={components}
            bordered
            columns={columnsToUseProdLoc}
            dataSource={productLocation.data}
            rowKey={record => record.key}>
          </Table>
        </Panel>
      </Collapse>
      <Divider />
    </>
  );
})}
```

Keys are generated using this method which seem unique :
`

```
const objTrend = { label: 'Trend', key: "Trend_" + element.product_id + "_" + element.location_id + key  };
```

`

When I log into my app however I get this error
"Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."
When I try to log rowKey on an updateEditedCell method rowKey returns undefined

When I check HTML code or my webpage I can see the correct data-row-key

Can you guys help me find out what's going on ?

I tried setting the rowKey using the rowKey attribute on my key property in the object but so far no result.

Comment: Can you create minimal working example using sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: I can't provide you that right now. However when I check the HTML code of the generated table I do see some data-row-key that are unique

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the keys before rendering, so it causes error and after that keys added